# Flutter: bottomNavigationBar item padding with text and label

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

The aim is to create a vertical padding for the BottomNavigationBarItem which encompasses both the label and icon. Currently, when I add the Padding, it creates padding for the entire bottomNavigationBar and I require it like the picture present below.

Aim:

[image]

The current output looks like this with 0 Padding:

[image]

Here is the code that is with 0 padding on the child:

```
  Widget bottomNavigationBar() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 65,// <---- This needs to be dynamic and not hard coded per se
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0x40000000), // 000000 with 28% opacity
              spreadRadius: 0,
              blurRadius: 4, 
              offset: Offset(0, 0), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          selectedItemColor: Color(0xFFffc107),
          unselectedItemColor: Color(0xFF666666),
          showSelectedLabels: true,
          selectedFontSize: 16,
          selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFFFFC107),
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
          unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF666666),
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
          unselectedFontSize: 16,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.campaign_outlined),
              label: 'What\'s new?',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
              label: 'Favourites',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
              label: 'Account',
            ),
          ],
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Edit: Updated the code as it needed Shadow and added it in Sizedbox as per the suggestions below in the post. Added comments too for the height which is hard coded.

Comment: What do you need to do? I don't get your question. can you please explain more bit?

Comment: @Hadiuzzaman I want to add vertical padding in the bottomNavBarItems, so essentially the icon and label are sandwiched between the padding, I have added the first image on top for better visualization. The red arrows is the padding that I require.

Comment: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8), can you try with this?

Comment: SizedBox(
height: 80,
child: BottomNavigationBar()
), 

replace your Padding widget with this. hope its works

Comment: @Hadiuzzaman Updated and editerd a part of the code based on your suggestion. Please see the edit

Comment: please check my answer now, hope it is fixed for you now

Comment: Hey, @Hadiuzzaman can you please give type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed in BottomNavigationBar and let me know this thing fixed your issue or not?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the label, use amColumn as an icon or Padding for icon only. This is Widget type, not icon.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Text(
              'Home',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

NOTE: You can hide labels of course/

Comment: Please can you elaborate this further so I can test this out.

Comment: Updated exmaple

Answer (score 0):

update your widget like below -

```dart
  Widget bottomNavigationBar() {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
      color: const Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        elevation: 0,
        items: [
       ...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Still having the expected issue: https://imgur.com/VvHOKW1

It's adding padding to the nav bar not the elements inside it